# Не срабатывает switch-case/if-else условие. Java

Tags: java, switch, case, if

Упражняюсь в Java на [Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/555615a77ebc7c2c8a0000b8/train/java). В задачке речь идет об очереди в кинотеатр, где билет на фильм стоит 25 долларов, а у посетителей могут быть купюры в 25, 50 и 100 долларов (автор кто-то из русских, судя по контексту).

Так вот, с самого начала у кассира Васи нет сдачи и вопрос состоит в том, сможет ли он обслужить очередь, продавая каждому из пришедших по одному билету. Т.е. на сдачу у него будут только те купюры, что он взял с начала работы, а если в какой-то момент у него не получается насобирать сдачу, то все - программа должна возвратить "NO".

Если же клиенты в очереди расположены так, что Васе удается "распетлять" со сдачей, и все люди в очереди (до последнего) смогли купить по билету и получить сдачу, то программа должна возвратить "YES".

> Line.Tickets(new int[] {25, 25, 50}) // => YES
>
> Line.Tickets(new int[]{25, 100}) // => NO. Vasya will not have enough money to give change to 100 dollars
>
> Line.Tickets(new int[] {25, 25, 50, 50, 100}) // => NO. Vasya will not have the right bills to give 75 dollars of change (you can't make two bills of 25 from one of 50)

У меня создается впечатление, что просто сразу срабатывает строчка

```
return "YES";
```

а программа в цикл и ветвления вообще не заходит...

```
public class Line {
  public static String Tickets(int[] peopleInLine) {
  int counter25 = 0;
  int counter50 = 0;
  int counter100 = 0;

for (int i=0; i < peopleInLine.length - 1; i++) {      
  switch (peopleInLine[i]) {
    case 25:
      counter25 = counter25 + 1;
      break;
    case 50:
      if (counter25 > 0) {
        counter50 = counter50 + 1;
        counter25 = counter25 - 1;  
      } else {
        return "NO";
      } 
      break;
    case 100:
      if (counter50 > 0 && counter25 > 0) {
        counter100 = counter100 + 1;
        counter50 = counter50 - 1;
        counter25 = counter25 - 1;
      } else if (counter50 == 0 && counter25 > 2) {
        counter100 = counter100 + 1;
        counter25 = counter25 - 3;
      } else {
        return "NO";
      }
      break;
  }
}
return "YES";
}   
}
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Почему условие выхода из цикла `i < peopleInLine.length - 1`? То есть если в очереди будет 1 человек, тело цикла не выполнится ни разу и вернется YES, даже в случае, если подать на вход единственное число 50 или 100. Должно быть либо `i < peopleInLine.length`, либо `i <= peopleInLine.length - 1`

Comment: Спасибо, исправил - заработало. Полдня голову ломал, изменяя конструкции ветвления....